# Read pdf in Android Studio

Tags: android, file, pdf

I would read a file pdf in my project.
1 step: Where do I input PDF File? in which folder?
2 step: How do I read it? I just  need to open it.

I found this code but give me an error: The directory of the file si wrong

```
protected void openPdf()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String path =      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+" /PDF";
        File file = new File(path, "law.pdf");
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What's the file path at that time? Did you put a breakpoint and check it?

Comment: File path: C:/Users/root/Desktop/Progetto Pitagora/File/pdf/law.pdf"

Comment: you might be getting some flack for that space in the folder name. Make sure you allow for that, and that the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

String path =      Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+" /PDF";

to `String path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";`